# Subset from different dataframes using 1 loop

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to create subsets of 3 original dataframes (data_A, data_B, data_c) based on the value of a certain variable that is shared across those datasets (i.e. workhours).
The value of the variable under which I want to create subsets will be the same across datasets.
I want the created subsets to be labeled as Dataset_1 to Dataset_11 for subsets of data_A, Dataset_12 to Dataset_22 for subsets of data_B, and Dataset_23 to Dataset_33 for subsets of data_C.

Right now I have the following solution:

```
for (i in 1:11){
  assign(paste0("Dataset_",i), subset(data_A, workhours>=(0+(i-1)*5)))
}

for (i in 12:22){
  assign(paste0("Dataset_",i), subset(data_B, workhours>=(0+(i-12)*5)))
}

for (i in 23:33){
  assign(paste0("Dataset_",i), subset(data_C, workhours>=(0+(i-23)*5)))
}
```

This works fine. However, is it possible to use merely 1 loop as opposed to 3?

EDIT:

solution:

```
for (i in 1:11){
    assign(paste0("Dataset_",i), subset(data_A, workhours>=((i-11)*5)))
    assign(paste0("Dataset_",i+11), subset(data_B, workhours>=((i)*5)))
    assign(paste0("Dataset_",i+23), subset(data_C, workhours>=((i)*5)))
}
```

another solution in can be found below

Comment: On your working example: 1. `0+` in all loops doesn't do anything. 2. Is it possible that in the first loop it should be `i-1` instead of `i-11`?

Comment: that is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:11){
    assign(paste0("Dataset_",i), subset(data_A, workhours>=((i-11)*5)))
    assign(paste0("Dataset_",i+11), subset(data_B, workhours>=((i)*5)))
    assign(paste0("Dataset_",i+23), subset(data_C, workhours>=((i)*5)))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `lapply` over list of dataframes and then use `split` with `findInterval` to split each dataframe into multiple dataframes.

```
bob <-list(data_A, data_B, data_C)
values <- seq(0, 50, 5)

temp <- unlist(lapply(bob, function(x) 
              split(x, findInterval(x$workhours, values))), recursive = FALSE)
names(temp) <- paste0('Dataset_', 1:33)
```

It is better to keep data in a list instead of polluting the global environment, however, if you still need them as separate dataframes we can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(temp, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, could you elaborate a bit on why it's not a good idea to pollute the global environment?

Comment: @Jeroen because lists are easier to manage. In the above case you need to manage only one object i.e `temp` instead of `Dataset_1`, `Dataset_2`, `Dataset_3` ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
       j in names(bob)
```

Right now, your are looping over the whole list in the j loop.